# Automatizing web browser form filling in Python

Tags: python, scripting, bots

#### Question:

Hi. I am a beginner trying to learn Python, and for one of my first projects **I want to write a script that will fill out a survey automatically for me**. I am familiar with coding, and I have most of the code written to solve this problem. What I am struggling is to write a method that will hit button #1 in question #1, or that will push any given button. One way I've realized I can do this, is perhaps by writing a script to press tab-> up-> down-> tab-> up -> down in the order needed to answer all of the questions.

Here is an image of what the survey looks like (CSS was disable for clarity).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/texeA.jpg

***What is one way to go about writing a method to push a radio button*?**

---

[**Disclaimer**]: I have checked out the following questions but they were of no use to me in my current situation:

- [fill out a webform that uses javascript with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128552/fill-out-a-webform-that-uses-javascript-with-python) (question was framed very strangely and was about Javascript forums, which I don't understand how it is relevant/ I didn't understand it, and nobody answered the question).
- [Script to take web survey for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364291/script-to-take-web-survey-for-me) (answers were only about Java, however something like this [tool called HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) seems cool, if there were a comparable library in Python).
- [How to fill out form data on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705112/how-to-fill-out-form-data-on-a-website) (question is about Java).

Comment: Do you mean like a bot? Try AutoPy.

Comment: Selenium - http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are Python libraries and tools for automatizing browser actions. StackOverflow.com is not a place to ask for an recommendation for such a tool and thus moderators will close this question (SO is usually asking a help for particular problem, not for broad help and tutoriing requests). However here are some starting points for you

- [Splinter - automate browser actions in Python](https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [Mechanize - Python library for stateful programmatic web browsing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)
- [Selenium automizing framework Python bindings](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) - using full installed browser
- [Headless web browsing listing - includes Python ones](https://gist.github.com/evandrix/3694955)
- [Scrapy - web content scraping framework in Python](http://scrapy.org/)

[For installing Python packages please refer to official package installation tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still struggling with asking the right kinds of SO questions, and the feedback is definitely useful. It's tough to get started on this site but people like you are helping push me in the right direction!

Comment: For tutoring I recommend `##python-friendly` IRC channel on Freenode. Web chat: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=##python-friendly - please be prepared to spend at least two hours to receive an answer (depending on the global office hours)

Comment: @josh-desmond The truth is that people ask questions like yours all the time on StackOverflow. There's nothing incompatible with your question; it wasn't closed after 2+ years; it answered my question; and the responder benefited -- reputation wise -- over time from replying to it. Win/Win. No problem.