# How to create a program in python that will auto-fill forms?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<html>

<div class="echo-chat-body" dir="ltr">
    <div class="new-chat-form">

        <div>
            <h1 class="echo-title desktop-only">
                Topic?
            </h1>
            <hr class="desktop-only full-width">
            <input id="topic" name="topic" autocomplete="false" placeholder="Topic?" class="js-chat-topic answer input input-text desktop-input js-chat-required-false" type="text">
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1 class="echo-title desktop-only">
                What's your name?
            </h1>
            <hr class="desktop-only full-width">
            <input id="name" name="name" autocomplete="false" placeholder="What&#39;s your name?" class="js-chat-name answer input input-text desktop-input js-chat-required-true" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="form-action">
            <label></label>
            <button id="startchat" class="echo-button button-secondary js-submit-new-chat center" disabled="">
                Start Chat
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Here is my Python code:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'file:///C:/Users/SuperDesktop/HTML/Desktop/Chat.html'
post_fields = {'topic': 'Hello', 'name' : 'My Name', 'startchat': 'startchat'}

"""
Topic is 'Hello'.
Name is 'My name'.
startchat is the button which should be clicked. 
" 'startchat': 'startchat' " is not the proper code to click the button.
"""

request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
print(json)
```

I tried that code but it always shows different errors.
How to create a program in python that will auto-fill those 2 boxes and click on submit?
I want to fill this form via python code, I don't want to use Selenium, Automated Browser or chromedriver
I don't want python code opening a browser and filling those things and clicking start button
I also tried to use Selenium, Automated Browser, opening browser and chrome driver but that was not the thing that I wanted.
I wanted a python code that will fill those boxes and send the form within Terminator.

Comment: maybe this article helps:

Comment: maybe this article helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932205/automatizing-web-browser-form-filling-in-python

Comment: I have seen those things but those are not helpful to me.